# Returning promises up?

Tags: javascript, promise

I was reading about javascript in MDN and came across this part that talks about promises and did not understand what it meant.

The code is pretty straight forward however I do not understand the word of caution. What does it mean to return promises up? What does it mean to return implicitly? If its a dumb question please point to some resource and I'll mark it as closed.

```
doSomething()
.then(result => doSomethingElse(result))
.then(newResult => doThirdThing(newResult))
.then(finalResult => {
console.log(`Got the final result: ${finalResult}`);
})
.catch(failureCallback);
```

Important: Always return promises up, otherwise callbacks won't chain, and errors won't be caught (arrow functions return implicitly when {} are left out).

Comment: regarding `return implicitly` - see [Arrow documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)

Comment: as far as returning promises up goes, it's pointing out that in your chain, don't forget to return any promises in `.then` (I think)

Comment: Just in the last months there were several questions here where People forgot to return the promise from a method and were asking on how to chain these methods. Or they had nested promises, also didn't return them, and were wondering that the subsequent `then`s weren't waiting for that nested promise to finish. I'd guess that's the kind of stuff they mean when speaking about the "Always return promises up".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return a promise up usually mean to be able to chain another `.then`.

Here you are not returning anything:

```
.then(finalResult => {
  console.log(`Got the final result: ${finalResult}`);
})
```

So you can't chain another `.then` after it.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments, `.then` actually always returns another promise.
But there is a catch, if your `resolve` callback won't return anything (`undefined`) then the caller of this promise will get `undefined` as the parameter.
So basically there is no gain in just chain "empty" `then`.

Here is a small running example of such case:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve("#1");
});

promise
  .then((result) => result)
  .then((result) => `${result} #2`)
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .then((result) => `${result} #4`) // <-- result === undefined
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .then((result) => '#7')
  .then((result) => console.log(result));
```

---

As for this statement:

> arrow functions return implicitly when {} are left out

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) can return in 2 ways:

**implicit:**

```
const func = () => 'hi there' // implicitly returns a string
```

But when there is a body for the function `{}` nothing is returned:

```
const func = () => {'hi there'} // nothing is returned
```

**explicitly**:

When we use the `return` key word:

```
 const func = () => { return 'hi there'; } // explicitly returns a string
```

**Gotchas:**
Sometimes you want to return an object, so there is a common mistake that people do:

```
const func = () => {a:1} // nothing is returned, just a meaningless label a
```

So a "fix" for that is to wrap the object with an expression:

```
const func = () => ({ a:1 }) // implicitly returns an object
```

Comment: Clear and concise. Thanks!!

Comment: *"Here you are not returning anything ... So you can't chain another `.then` after it."* this is not correct. `then()` ALWAYS returns a promise wich provides you with another `then` method. Afaik, the most common behaviour is that if your function returns `undefined` the following promise will also resolve to the same value as its predecessor.

Comment: @Thomas i'll ad clarification